# ffmpeg how to place still image over full vstack?

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to build a simple video editor and im using ffmpeg on the background. I want as much different filters/properties in one command but im not succeeding in placing a still image before everything else (first frame). I want a vstack after the image has shown in a video.

I tried a lot of different commands etc. and most of the time the video renders but the image included in the vstack, or the video doesn't start for the amount of seconds I want the still image to be shown.

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "header.jpg" -i "video.mp4" -i "footer" -i "still-image.jpg" -filter_complex "[1][3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,4)';vstack=inputs=3" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -y output.mp4`

Most of the time I don't get an error. It just isn't doing what's expected. The above command is one of the many I tried but is basically what I want. Can someone help please?

Comment: It is not really clear what you need.

Comment: I want a video where there is a still image before it begins. But the video also has to have a vstack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. This method delays the vstack and overlays `still-image.jpg` during the delay.

```
ffmpeg -i "header.jpg" -i "video.mp4" -i "footer.jpg" -i "still-image.jpg" -filter_complex "[0][1][2]vstack=inputs=3[v0];[v0]tpad=start_duration=4[bg];[bg][3]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,4)',format=yuv420p[v];[1:a]adelay=4s:all=true[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Requires FFmpeg 4.2 or newer.